# Extending object with properties in class diagram (Composition or inheritance)

Tags: oop, design-patterns, uml, class-diagram, class-design

[image]

So, I'm in the process of designing a small system for which I'm starting out with making a class diagram. (Before however I proceed, I guess it is fair to say, that the properties visualized here have different naming in the real system)

The small snippet displays the following:

- Engine can generate either a `DefaultAlgorithm` or a `DecoratedAlgorithm`
- `Engine`, `DecoratedAlgorithm` and `DefaultAlgorithm` have `Algorithm` as an associated property
- `Engine` needs the properties from `Algorithm` in order to generate either `DefaultAlgorithm` or `DecoratedAlgorithm`
- `DefaultAlgorithm` and `DecoratedAlgorithm` both need the properties from `Algorithm` because those properties are metadata that tells how the algorithms were generated.
- `DefaultAlgorithm` and `DecoratedAlgorithm` will besides being consumed by other classes (that reads `algo` and corresponding properties) also be persisted in a database where nested properties might not be desirable.

When I look at above diagram, I dont feel that things look quite right, for example will the properties of `Algorithm` be deeply nested, making me have to write awkward code to access the properties.

To me, possible alternative options could be:

- Extend `DefaultAlgorithm`, `Engine` and `DecoratedAlgorithm` with `Algorithm`, not caring about "Composition over inheritance"
- Carelessly repeat myself and add the properties to respectively `DefaultAlgorithm`, `Engine` and `DecoratedAlgorithm`

I know this might be a broad question, but what I hope with this question is to get some feedback on my thought process (Since I fear that I might be overthinking this)

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand where your issue is. Where is there any _nesting_ for  `Algorithm` properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `DefaultAlgorithm` or the `DecoratedAlgorithm` in place of `Algorithm`, they should either all implement a [common interface](https://www.oodesign.com/amp/decorator-pattern/), or the more specialised algorithms should inherit from the general `Algorithm`.

Repeating doesn’t seem to be a wise approach, because if Algorithm would evolve and change some properties, you’d need to change all the others as well. This is not compliant with the [open/closed principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle).

If you go for the extensiin approach, you could make your properties protected. Nevertheless, this is not a good idea in view of the history rule of [Liskov’s Substitution Principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): protected members are a leakage of internal details that proved to cause very nasty bugs.

In this regard, the problem is elsewhere.  Rather than querying the algorithm to get the properties, you should tell the algorithm to to something (up to the algorithm to see which property is relevant). [**Tell, don’t ask**](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html). This would lead to more OO, in the spirit of the [principle of the least knowledge](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

If you implement this principle, “deeply nested properties”, i.e. properties that are themselves objects of a complex class, should no longer be a problem. By the way, nested properties in UML are equivalent to associations (the property being an owned association end). Persisting such classes is supported by well known techniques (serialising, transformstion to a flat rdbms model, etc…)

Comment: Hi @Christope, that was exactly the type of answer I was expecting - Thanks alot!